# Python Desktop Integration - Drag and drop

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, pygame, desktop-integration

I have a pygame window that I want to know when a file has been dragged and dropped onto it. I only need to be able to fetch the name of the file. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Did you succeed? Because I am trying the exact same thing, and it doesn't work... (Using pythoncom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [forum thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2008-April/007406.html) that might be what you're looking for.

And [another](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2008-September/008209.html) forum.

And a link to the [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678486(VS.85).aspx).  You'll probably want the [pythoncom](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/pythoncom.html) library.

Answer (score 0):

one option for a similar effect is is to use pygame's scrap module so you can copy-paste into the window, your program would just need to look for ctr-V events.

On this XFCE desktop I'm using 
If I hit ctrl-C with a file selected, the file name shows up when I type

```
pygame.scrap.init()

types= pygame.scrap.get_types()

print dict(
    [type,pygame.scrap.get(type)] 
    for type intypes
)
```